# Aligning at the equal sign while keeping whole block aligned to the left

Tags: math-mode

In my TeX document, I have my equations all pushed to the left instead of appearing in the center and I have it set so the output is a single "sheet" cropped to the output. The code for it is this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
…
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
% Equations go here.
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I want to get an equation to look like this:

```
f(x) = k * (x + c) + z
     = k * x + k * c + z
```

I'd like the lines that come after the first one to be aligned to the equal sign in the first and I want to keep it all in `$…$`. I can do that in OpenOffice using `%phantom{}`, but I don't know how to do that with LaTeX.

Comment: Are you looking for the `fleqn` option?

Comment: @marmot I have no idea what that is.

Comment: `\documentclass[fleqn, ...]{article}`.

Comment: May I ask *why* you insist on placing the formulae inside `$...$`?

Comment: @GuM I want to keep it inbetween a pair of dollar signs because that makes it easy to distinguish math formatting from non-math formatting in the source code.

Comment: No, I was referring to the reason why you want to avoid the standard environments for displayed equations.

Comment: @Melab, sorry, but use `$...$` is intended for inline math expressions (in text). to have display math (in own line, with display math style, which in many details differ from in-line math), you should use standard dispaly math environments as `\begin{equation} ...\end{equation}` or `\begin{align} ...\end{align}` etc. it's easy to recognize them in the editor. so your claim does not hold and your use of `$` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment. Just add the `fleqn` option to your document.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla
\begin{align}
f(x) &= k * (x + c) + z \notag\\
       &= k * x + k * c + z
\end{align}    
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to keep it in a `$…$`.

Comment: @Melab what is "it" and did you notice that `align` is a math environment, which, as the name suggests, aligns lines of equations? (That is, everything inside an `align` environment is in math mode.)

Comment: "It" refers to the whole equation and I want to keep it inbetween a pair of dollar signs because that makes it easy to distinguish math formatting from non-math formatting in the source code.

Comment: @Melab But there is no need for that. Putting something between `$` signs just means you put the stuff in math mode. The `align` environment also does that.

Comment: @marmot -- i think this would more suitably be handled with `equation` and `split` since it has only one equation number.  and really, the op needs to read some basic `amsmath` documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Well, this is a matter of taste, I guess. It is not even clear if the OP wants to have an equation number. In any case, thanks to your comment (s)he is now also aware of the `split` option (which I personally never use). And I fully agree with your second comment. (I've also seen that the OP asked already a number of questions, got good answers and didn't bother to accept any of them...)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `\phantom` inside math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
$f(x) = k \times (x + c) + z$

$\phantom{f(x) =} = k \times x + k \times c + z$
\end{flushleft}

$
\begin{array}{ @{} r @{} l @{} }
  f(x) = {} & k \times (x + c) + z \\
            & = k \times x + k \times c + z
\end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, alignment is also possible if you place content inside an `array` (second option provided above).

Comment: Can I use `\phantom{}` inside the same pair of dollar signs after a double backslash?

Comment: @Melab: Inside `array`? Yup.